# How to display the slider module only on the homepage?

Tags: php, prestashop

I'm bothered by the fact that the `"slider"` module is displayed on all pages when I want it to be displayed only on the homepage. I've added the code line below but with no result. I did the same thing for the `"block_category"` module and it worked there. So I don't really know what's causing the problem.

```
{if $page_name == index}

  homeslider.tpl conent

{/if}
```

Comment: Have you did some changed in the module?

Answer (score 1):

You should Login with admin then you can edit SLider from homepage.
Move your cursor on Slider and from Slider you can edit slider then come below on page.
You will find slider setting then Select "Radio" button for the setting only on this page and then write in below textbox "`<front>`" for to show slider only on Homepage.

Answer (score 0):

By default the "slider" module (Image slider for your homepage) is assigned to the "home" page so it will appear only on this page. You can't assign it to any other hook.